# php code inside echo...how to manage it?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to do the following. This does not work. But how can I get it to work? I want to make a table populate with a php loop.

```
echo "<table>";
echo    "<thead>";
echo        "<tr>";
echo            "<th scope=\"col\"> Column1 </th>";
echo            "<th scope=\"col\"> Column2 </th>";
echo            "<th scope=\"col\"> Column3 </th>";
echo        "</tr>";
echo    "</thead>";
echo    <tbody>
echo        <tr>
echo            <?php while($row = MySQL_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
echo                <?php $link = $row['mirlyn'];?>
echo                <td><?php echo(htmlentities($row['data1'])); ?></td>
echo                <td><?php echo(htmlentities($row['data2'])); ?></td>
echo                <td><?php echo(htmlentities($row['data3'])); ?></td>
echo            <?php}?>
echo        </tr>               
echo    </tbody>
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: How is not working? What is it doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need all those echos. Please read up on proper PHP syntax. www.php.net is an amazing resource.

Comment: It seems like you haven't covered the basics as of yet. Plz buy a book. It'l help you in the long run.

Comment: @redel -what do you mean how? Did you look at the code? I suggest he reads some basic php tutorials.

Comment: Might I suggest that you read a book or similar for an introduction to PHP? Your code looks like you could use some guidance in mastering the language.

Comment: @redel - No I mean the OP. I was remarking on how it is impossible to overlook the echo on every single line. that in combination with the <?php while already inside php is enough to assume the OP has just started programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break out out php and just write the HTML like you normally would. When you need to output something in PHP, open a tag and do what you need to do

i.e.

```
<table>
    <tr><?php echo $something ?></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code it should work!!

```
      <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"> Column1 </th>
                <th scope="col"> Column2 </th>
                <th scope="col"> Column3 </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <?php while ($row = MySQL_fetch_array($result)): ?> 
                    <?php $link = $row['mirlyn']; ?>
                    <td><?php echo(htmlentities($row['data1'])); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo(htmlentities($row['data2'])); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo(htmlentities($row['data3'])); ?></td>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </tr>               
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to construct an HTML string to be echoed later you can use [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) like this -

```
$html = '<table>';

while($row = MySQL_fetch_array($result)){
  $html .= '<tr>';
  $html .= '<td>' . $someData . '</td>';
  $html .= '</tr>';
}

$html .= '</table>';
echo $html;
```

You only need to echo the final string out once, but each time you iterate over another result you just append it to the end of the string.  In PHP, string concatenation is done with the dot character.

```
stringOne.stringTwo
```

Will give you

```
stringOnestringTwo
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use concatenation to do this:

```
echo "               <td>" . htmlentities($row['data1']) . "</td>";
```

Or, you primarily output HTML and drop into PHP only when necessary.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a sample database queried table

```
$accounts = $currentMember->retrieve_all_accounts(); //Same error in instructor source file as I had in last assignment. 

    /* Loop through Accounts */
    while($account = mysqli_fetch_assoc($accounts)) {
        // Retrieve Balance
        $bankaccount = new Bankaccount($account['BankAccountID']);
        $bankaccount->connection = $conn;
        $balance = mysqli_fetch_assoc($bankaccount->retrieve_current_balance());

        echo '<tr>' . "\n";
        echo "\t" . '<td class="account_number">' . $account['BankAccountID'] . '</td>' . "\n";
        echo "\t" . '<td class="account_balance">$' . number_format($balance['CurrentBalance'], 2) . '</td>' . "\n";
        echo '</tr>' . "\n";
    }
```

Comment: A rule of thumb. Keep html tags far away from php as possible. Means, seperate them when possible. Sometimes, you don't have a choice but in the above case, you do.